# Unable to access certain sites via Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I am have a small office in which I use a Wireless Router to connect my office PCs (I have 10 PCs) in LAN.

Recently I am facing a strange issue.

Symptoms are:

1. Sometimes when I try to open a site from LAN PC, it does not open the first time. When I refresh the browser, then it opens.
2. When I try to open Google on my iPod (which is connected via Wifi) it opens Google fine. But when I try to open Facebook, it says "Safari cannot open the page because the server cannot be found".
3. Even when we try to connect to Facebook via its API, we get Site is offline message. 
   On that same PC, if we open Facebook.com in browser, it opens fine.

I have not kept any kind of blocking for any sites. And I have 12 MBPS broadband plan.

Not sure how to resolve this issue.

Can you please help?

Comment: Sounds like faulty DNS; When you can't reach a site by name, can you reach it by IP address?  Have you tried a different public DNS server?  When things are acting up, does rebooting the router help any?

Comment: I am using OpenDNS to connect to the internet. How do I know IP address of Facebook? I have tried rebooting the router, but it does not work.

Comment: Thanks Techie007. We resolved the issue. It was DNS which was entered differently at two different places. Making them same solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is what [Techie007](https://superuser.com/users/23133/techie007) mentioned:

> Sounds like faulty DNS; When you can't reach a site by name, can you reach it by IP address? Have you tried a different public DNS server? When things are acting up, does rebooting the router help any